# Extending a typescript module

Tags: typescript

I want to extend rxjs `Observable`.
I'm following the instructions from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2821

I have 2 files:

`rx.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="./rx.d.ts" />

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

Observable.prototype.trace = function() {
    return this.do(x => console.log(x))
}
```

`rx.d.ts`:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx'

export { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

declare module "rxjs/Rx" {
    interface Observable<T> {
        trace(): Observable<T>;
        traceMessage(message: string): Observable<T>;
    }
}
```

`rx.ts` compilation fails with message `Cannot find name 'Observable'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to export in your rx.d.ts file. This should be enough:

```
// rx.d.ts
declare module "rxjs/Rx" {
  interface Observable<T> {
    trace(): Observable<T>;
    traceMessage(message: string): Observable<T>;
  }
}
```

Secondly, it seems like you are trying to add a implement the method of an interface. You should implement the method on the class that the `Observable` interface describes. This eg. should compile just fine.

```
// rx.ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

let theObservable: Observable<any>
theObservable.trace().trace().trace().trace()
```